# Are there Complex eigenvalues in a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If a matrix is Hermitian, then its eigenvalues are all real. But given any **real** matrix that is **not Hermitian**, how to determine whether there are complex eigenvalues or not?

Or the question can be re-formulated in this way: rather than Hermitian, are there any more general rules which can be used to determine whether the eigenvalues of a matrix are all real numbers?

EDIT:
I could think of another solution to this (it is only an indirect way compared with the Hermitian matrix):

> If a matrix is similar to a Hermitian matrix, then its eigenvalues are all real.

Comment: Every square matrix has complex eigen values by the Fundamental theorem of algebra (eigen values are roots of the characteristic polynomial).

Comment: @Batman You are wrong. Normal matrices can have complex eigenvalues. For example, $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$ is a normal matrix but has complex conjugate eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding eigenvalue problems for general matrices is just as difficult as solving general polynomial equations, as seen by the matrices of the form 
$$A_n=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1  & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &\cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1 \\-a_0 & -a_1 & -a_2 & \cdots & -a_{n-1}  \end{bmatrix}, $$
whose characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^n+a_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1}+\dots+a_1 \lambda+a_0$. Some information about the "realness" of the roots can be obtained via the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Real_roots).

Comment: Thank you. But for polynomials of higher degrees ($\ge 4$), the information given by the discriminant is still limited. Let $D$ denotes the discriminant. if $D=0$, then there are no complex eigenvalues, while there are at least two complex eigenvalues if $D<0$. However, we cannot determine in the case where $D>0$.